# Discord.py not showing output

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

So, I'm new to discord.py and I was recently making my new bot. I made a coin flip command but for some reason it is not working. It isn't showing any output at all. It is also not showing any kind of error in console. Here's my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import random
import time

client= commands.Bot(command_prefix="ak!")

@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")


@client.command()

async def coinflip(ctx):
    
    action= random.randint(0, 1)
    if(action == 0):
        flip= "Tails"
    elif(action == 1):
        flip= "Heads"

    time.sleep(1)
    embed= discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name} has flipped the coin!", description=f"{flip} it is!")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)



client.run("token")
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is this all of your bot?

Comment: Yes that's all.

Comment: Did you try the code in the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a intent update on discord.py 1.5.1
So try to define bot like this:

```
from discord import Intents
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

intent = Intents().all()

bot = Bot(command_prefix='prefix', intents=intent)

... # Some code under this line
```